# Ember modify object's property in action

Tags: ember.js

The problem is that I would like to have two level menu. Second level for each menu element will be shown after click. If you click again it should hide submenus. So I thought I can do this by toggling CSS class on first level menu elements.

Component.js - so far I want to have 2 main menu elements.

```
menus: [{
            'name': 'Dashboard',
            'icon': 'dashboard',
            'active': false,
            submenus: [{
                ...
            }]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Settings',
            'icon': 'cloud',
            'active': false,
            submenus: [{
                 ...
            }], 
        }
    ],
```

And in the template I am dynamically generating HTML elements. I've bound active property with class, so if it changes in component.js it should affect CSS class.

```
{{#each menus as |menu|}}
    <li class="collapsible" {{bind-attr class="menu.active:active"}} {{action 'toggle' menu}}>
        <a ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{menu.icon}}"></span>{{menu.name}}</a>
        <ul>
           {{#each menu.submenus as |submenu|}}
               {{#link-to submenu.route activeClass="selected" tagName="li"}}
                   <a href=""><{{submenu.name}}</a>
               {{/link-to}}
           {{/each}}
       </ul>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

So at the end I define a simple action for toggling *active* parameters of first level menus.

```
actions: {
    toggle: function(menu) {
        this.toggleProperty(menu.active);
    }
}
```

But with it says that I haven't specified element as string.
And if I change it to `menu.toggleProperty('active')` it says that toggleProperty is not a function.

Can you advise me? Thanks

Comment: What version of Ember.js are you using? `bind-attr` is pre 2.0.

Comment: It sounds like `menu` isn't an Ember.Object, so it wouldn't have the `toggleProperty` method available on it.

Comment: Ember version is 2.3.0.
When i am logging menu it prints object correctly, but when I try to run toggleProperty - it says it is not a function.
P.S - thanks for edit

Comment: It's strange that `bind-attr` isn't giving you an error, it was removed in 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're getting that error because `menu` isn't an `Ember.Object`. You could do it manually:

```
actions: {
  toggle(menu) {
    Ember.set(menu, 'active', !Ember.get(menu, 'active'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it normal that this is not an Ember.Object? And thank for pointing out that bind-attr is deprecated:)

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Ember.js should automatically wrap arrays in Ember.Array if you don't have native extensions turned off, but not objects.